# Script works in powershell but not c#

Tags: c#, powershell, active-directory, terminal-services

This script works when running in PowerShell ISE (it sets the given user's **Remote Desktop Services Profile** settings in Active Directory):

```
Get-ADUser FirstName.LastName | ForEach-Object {
    $User = [ADSI]"LDAP://$($_.DistinguishedName)"
    $User.psbase.invokeset("TerminalServicesProfilePath","\\Server\Share\HomeDir\Profile")
    $User.psbase.invokeset("TerminalServicesHomeDrive","H:")
    $User.psbase.invokeset("TerminalServicesHomeDirectory","\\Server\Share\HomeDir") 
    $User.setinfo()
}
```

But when I try running it from a C# application I get an error for each `invokeset` that I call:

> Exception calling "InvokeSet" with "2" argument(s):
>
> "Unknown name. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020006 (DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME))"

Here is the code, which is inside my `PowerShell` class:

```
public static List<PSObject> Execute(string args)
{
    var returnList = new List<PSObject>();

    using (var powerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        powerShellInstance.AddScript(args);
        var psOutput = powerShellInstance.Invoke();


        if (powerShellInstance.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var error in powerShellInstance.Streams.Error)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(error);
            }
        }

        foreach (var outputItem in psOutput)
        {
            if (outputItem != null)
            {
                returnList.Add(outputItem);
            }
        }
    }

    return returnList;
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
var script = $@"
                Get-ADUser {newStarter.DotName} | ForEach-Object {{
                    $User = [ADSI]""LDAP://$($_.DistinguishedName)""
                    $User.psbase.invokeset(""TerminalServicesProfilePath"",""\\file\tsprofiles$\{newStarter.DotName}"")
                    $User.psbase.invokeset(""TerminalServicesHomeDrive"",""H:"")
                    $User.psbase.invokeset(""TerminalServicesHomeDirectory"",""\\file\home$\{newStarter.DotName}"") 
                    $User.setinfo()
                }}";

PowerShell.Execute(script);
```

Where `newStarter.DotName` contains the (already existing) AD user's account name.

---

I tried including `Import-Module ActveDirectory` at the top of the `C#` script, but with no effect. I also called `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion` in both the script running normally and the `C#` script and both return that version 3 is being used.

---

After updating the property names to

```
msTSProfilePath
msTSHomeDrive
msTSHomeDirectory
msTSAllowLogon
```

I am getting this error in C#:

> Exception calling "setinfo" with "0" argument(s): "The attribute syntax specified to the directory service is invalid.

And querying those properties in PowerShell nothing (no error but also no output)

---

Does anyone happen to know what could cause this?

Many thanks

Comment: try adding import-module for ad in the script you are running in c#.

Comment: @Abhijithpk Just tried adding `Import-Module ActiveDirectory` to the script but still seeing the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Updated answer:* It seems that these attributes don't exist in 2008+. Try these ones instead:

- msTSAllowLogon
- msTSHomeDirectory
- msTSHomeDrive
- msTSProfilePath

See the answer in [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/eb6e172e-459b-42fa-928c-f6688bdafde6/unable-to-retrieve-terminal-service-properties-from-native-adds-object-directoryentryinvokeget) for the full explanation.

*Original Answer:*

The comment from *Abhijith pk* is probably the answer. You need to run `Import-Module ActiveDirectory`, just like you need to do in the command line PowerShell.

If you've ever run `Import-Module ActiveDirectory` in the PowerShell command line, you'll know it takes a while to load. It will be the same when run in C#. So if you will be running several AD commands in your application, you would be better off keeping a Runspace object alive as a static object and reuse it, which means you only load the ActiveDirectory module once.

There is details here about how to do that in C#:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/syamp/2011/02/24/how-to-run-an-active-directory-ad-cmdlet-from-net-c/

Particularly, this is the code:

```
InitialSessionState iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault(); 
iss.ImportPSModule(new string[] { "activedirectory" }); 
Runspace myRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(iss); 
myRunSpace.Open();
```

Comment: Hi Gabriel thanks for your answer. I tried including `Import-Module ActiveDirectory` at the top of the script, but I am still seeing the same error. Do you know what else might cause this?

Comment: I've updated my answer. It seems you may need to look at different properties if your AD is running on Windows Server 2008+.

Comment: Thanks I will give that a try. Is it possible for that to be the issue fit he same command is working from inside PowerShell? (Still contacting the same server)

Comment: Yes. Now that I'm in the office, I tried it myself and I was getting the same "Unknown name" error using "TerminalServicesProfilePath" but it worked with "msTSProfilePath".

Comment: I changed the property names but now I am seeing this error: `Exception calling "setinfo" with "0" argument(s): "The attribute syntax specified to the directory service is invalid.` I updated my question

Comment: Which version of Windows Server are your domain controllers running?

Comment: I just asked the sysadmin and he says our Active Directory is targeted by 2 different controllsers, one being on 2003 and the other on 2008

Comment: Maybe you can check which attributes are available. Use ADUC and open any user account and go to the "Attribute Editor" tab. Make sure the filters are off and look for the msTS attributes in the list.

Comment: It's really weird, I can see all of the `msTS` properties, but none of them have any values (even the ones where I can see that the user does have a profile path and home dir etc). I can also see some of the other properties (`homeDirectory`, `profilePath`),  some of which do have values in Attribute Editor, but not under the `Remote Desktop Services Profile` tab... it all seems very inconsistent - either that or I don't understand these properties at all

Comment: The `homeDrive` and `homeDirectory` attributes correspond to the fields under 'Home folder' on the 'Profile' tab. If those are populated, that drive will be mapped when the user logs in to any computer. Is that what you are after?

Comment: And the `profilePath` field corresponds to the 'Profile path' field on the 'Profile' tab.