# How do i access the remote desktop services user profile path programatically?

Tags: c#, powershell, active-directory, windows-10, windows-server-2008-r2

So, there's a couple of these posted that are a bit "older" but I'm just now coming across this and am unable to get ahold of these properties.

Basically what I need is to be able to access the "Remote Desktop Services User Profile Path" that's in Active directory. I've tried several things online including ADSI for powershell but the "TerminalServicesHomeDirectory" attritube or property whatever you want to call it just comes back with nothing in it. I also tried the following code which is supposed to be able to set it. this didn't work either.

```
        PrincipalContext PC = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
        UserPrincipal UP = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(PC, "testact");
        DirectoryEntry DE = (DirectoryEntry)UP.GetUnderlyingObject();
        DE.InvokeSet("TerminalServicesHomeDirectory", new object[] { "testing" });
        DE.CommitChanges();
```

I know I read somewhere that you were supposed to use the "tsuserex.dll" however I've been unsuccessful getting that to add as a reference. I found two of them on my machine, one listed in system32 and one in "c:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64......." but neither of them load. they just generate an error

```
"a reference to $pathhere\tsuserex.dll could not be added. please make sure
the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component."
```

I've pretty much scoured the internet so now I'm hoping the all powerful SO can come to my rescue. I'm on a 64bit windows 10 machine by the way.

Comment: Never mind, apparently this code works. I posted this to SO after trying 100 times and it randomly started working without any code changes. you guys scared it into submission :) thanks.

Comment: Some PS suggestions: [This](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/2bd5fe5d-6e75-4548-b3ee-e488f51ab1f7/changing-the-remote-desktop-profile-path-with-powershell?forum=winserverpowershell) and [this](https://explorepowershell.com/2012/12/24/checking-setting-remote-desktop-services-profile-settings/)

Comment: For anyone who got stuck on this you can also use 
    DE.InvokeGet("TerminalServicesProfilePath") to get the value.

Comment: I just answered this for someone else here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45106182/unable-to-get-active-directory-terminal-services-attributes-while-running-powers/45179786#45179786
Disregard the fact they are using the solution inside of C#, all the necessary PowerShell is present.

Comment: Ty, my solution is a lot more simple than that though it's just 4 short lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out my solution was correct the whole time it just took a bit to update i guess.

```
    PrincipalContext PC = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
    UserPrincipal UP = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(PC, "testact");
    DirectoryEntry DE = (DirectoryEntry)UP.GetUnderlyingObject();
    //To Change the value
    DE.InvokeSet("TerminalServicesHomeDirectory", new object[] { "testing" });
    DE.CommitChanges();
    //to get the value
    string value = DE.InvokeGet("TerminalServicesHomeDirectory");
```

this is all the code you need to get or change those values. you can also do it with the TerminalServicesProfilePath property.